# Actionscript3 SSL sockets

Tags: flash, security, google-app-engine, actionscript, ssl

In the application we are working on we have to send secured messages from a flash movie running in the browser to an app engine application. One good candidate would be SSL which app engine seems to somewhat support (not exactly sure). But is there any implementation for SSL sockets for actionscript 3 (since afaik as3 doesn't have SSL support)?

Has anyone worked with a similar setup? Any ideas? What if we can't use SSL, what other security scenario can we use?

Thanks,

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetConnection.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/c9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000347.html

http://flexexamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/flex-using-ssl.html

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2196613

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Flash Player 11 or AIR 2, the SecureSocket class is another option:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html